# fill a list with a parameter in an object list c#

Tags: c#, list

Good morning,
I'm looking for a more efficient way to fill a list of any type with an object parameter.

Example (my class) :

```
public class Thème
{
    public string Thème_ { get; set; }
    public Liste[] Listes { get; set; }
}
```

My code that I currently have to do what I want to do:

```
        List<string> nomDesThèmesDisponible = new List<string>();

        foreach(Thème thème in Data.Thèmes)
        {
            nomDesThèmesDisponible.Add(thème.Thème_);
        }
```

I think there's an easier way to do that (with linq?).

Thank you for offering me your solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
nomDesThèmesDisponible.AddRange(Data.Thèmes.Select(t => t.Thème_));
```

or

```
nomDesThèmesDisponible = Data.Thèmes.Select(t => t.Thème_).ToList();
```

These ways not anymore efficient, just more concise.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> nomDesThèmesDisponible = Data.Thèmes.Select (t => t.Thème_).ToList();
```